# How to list github users that contains specified string using github api?

Tags: javascript, typescript, github, github-api

I wish to get list of users, whereby its username contains string I specify in the query. The only options I know to list users is another endpoint that github api provides, but it only shows maximum to first 100 default users.

```
await octokit.request('GET /users/{username}', {
  username: 'string',
  headers: {
    'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
  }
})
```

Need help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-users), you can use the key `since` to help you.

For every request, you check if the return list has a length equal to 100 (since that is your per-request size, can vary with your parameter).

If it is 100, continue to query the same API, but pass the id of the last user of the result into `since` parameter, so that you can query the next 100 users.

method 1 (recommended): use pagination from `octokit` as documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/using-pagination-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#using-link-headers)

```js
import { Octokit } from "octokit";

const octokit = new Octokit({ });

//! notice the use of paginate here
const data = await octokit.paginate("GET /users/{username}", {
  per_page: 100,
  headers: {
    "X-GitHub-Api-Version": "2022-11-28",
  },
});

console.log(data)
```

method 2: Keep looping it until the list does not have 100 users, i.e. end of the entire list.

a quick mock up

```js
// MOCK ONLY

let users = [];
let last_user = 0;
while (True) {
  let query = await fetch(`/users/{username}`, {
    since: last_user
  });

  users.push(query.data.users);

  if (query.data.users.length < 100 {
    break;
  }

  last_user = query.data.users[query.data.users.length - 1]
}
```